# make citation callout different for books than for articles

Tags: bibliographies

I'm using natbib with style "apalike", like this:

```
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
...
\citep{jones_2005} % this is a journal article
\citep{gray_1988} % this is a book
...
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{./bibliographyfile}
```

Which generates cite labels (the ones in the text) like this

- article: (Jones et. al., 2005)
- books: (Gray, 1988)

I'd like the books and only the books to appear including their title, like this:

- (Quantum theory of solids, Gray, 1988)

I couldn't find anything helpful regarding this in the natbib manual, but maybe there are some tricks to still make it work?

Comment: The short answer is, it can't be done with `natbib`/`bibtex`. It *may* be possible with `biblatex`, but I'm not positive. Hopefully some `biblatex` experts will notice your posting.